# ¿Como pasar por posición?

Tags: php, javascript, html, axios, table

A continuación les muestro una tabla dinámica la cual lleno a través de un API, quisiera me apoyaran en lo siguiente.

```
    function llenarTabla() {
    document.querySelector('#tabla-usuarios 
       tbody').innerHTML = '';
         for (let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++) {
      document.querySelector('#tabla-usuarios 
        tbody').innerHTML +=
        `<tr>
    <td>${usuarios[i].nombre} </td>
    <td>${usuarios[i].fechaNacimiento}</td>
    <td>${usuarios[i].email}</td>
    <td>${usuarios[i].usuario}</td>
    <td>${usuarios[i].rol}</td>
    
    <input type="hidden" name="nombre" 
     value="${usuarios[i].nombre} ">
    <input type="hidden" name="fechaNacimiento" 
     value="${usuarios[i].fechaNacimiento}">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" 
     value="${usuarios[i].email} ">
    <input type="hidden" name="usuario" 
     value="${usuarios[i].usuario}">
    <input type="hidden" name="rol" 
       value="${usuarios[i].rol}">

    <td>
    <button type="button" 
     onclick="eliminar(${i})">X</button>
    <button type="button" 
      onclick="seleccionar(${i})">Seleccionar</button>
    <input type="submit" name="boton" value="Editar"> 
    </td>
    </tr>`;
      }
     }
```

Lo que quiero realizar es que al seleccionar a un usuario los datos de ese usuario se pasen otro formulario en el cual yo pueda mostrarlos en inputs de tipo texto.

La función llenarTabla la lleno a traves de la siguiente función

```
       function obtenerUsuarios() {
        axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://dynns.com/api/App/consultausu',
       responseType: 'json'
        }).then(res => {
         console.log(res.data);
        this.usuarios = res.data;
         llenarTabla();
        }).catch(error => {
         console.error(error);
        });

              }
            obtenerUsuarios();
```

La funcion seleccionar por el mometo solo redirecciona, pero no sé como pasarle los datos para así enviarlos a la página que quiero

```
   function seleccionar(usuario) {
   console.log('Se seleccionó el usuario' + `${usuarios[usuario].usuario}`);

    axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: window.location.href = 
   'http://localhost/LaudemAVE/sistema/actualizarUsuario.php',
   
      }).then(res => {
     console.log(res);

     }).catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
    });
      }
```

Comment: Por favor muestra la función seleccionar() para saber qué hace, o indica qué quieres que haga. ¿Como obtienes el array de usuarios? ¿tienen algún identificador? En mi caso, hace falta información para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta amigo, espero puedas apoyarme

Comment: 1. en la plantilla asigna ponle ids a los tr para facilitar su acceso algo así: como `<tr id="linea-${i}">` pues estás pasando ${i} como parámetro al método. De modo que lo consistente es usarlo para leer la línea seleccionada. (guarda copia de la pregunta, pues te voy a llevar de la mano)

Comment: Gracias amigo, no sé si será mucho pedir que nos comuniquemos por gmail por favor, te dejo mi correo jdanielhjimenez@gmail.com

Comment: una pregunta `console.log('Se seleccionó el usuario' + `${usuarios[usuario].usuario}`);` te muestra el usuario? Nos ahorramos muchuos pasos si la variable usuario es visible en el método.

Comment: Si, me muestra en consola el usuario que selecciono

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113269/discussion-between-quevedo-and-daniel-jimenez).

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas en la petición AJAX:

1. En lugar de especificar solo la URL también estás modificando la ubicación del navegador: `url: **window.location.href** = 'http://localhost/LaudemAVE/sistema/actualizarUsuario.php'`, no estoy seguro si realiza la petición AJAX o solo una redirección... ¿o ambas?
2. No estás enviando parámetros

```
function seleccionar(usuario) {
   console.log('Se seleccionó el usuario' + `${usuarios[usuario].usuario}`);

    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        // Solo URL
        url: 'http://localhost/LaudemAVE/sistema/actualizarUsuario.php',
        // Enviar dato de usuario
        data: { usuario: usuarios[usuario].usuario }
      }).then(res => {
     console.log(res);

     }).catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
    });
 }
```

En PHP debes recibir sin problema el parámetro en `$_POST['usuario'];`, pero me queda la inquietud de pareces tener todos los usuarios cargados en un arreglo y, probablemente, no haya necesidad de una petición AJAX para mostrar el formulario.

Comment: Si exacto amigo, como tal es una tabla html, la cual genero dinamicamente en js, los datos están en un arreglo que se llama usuarios[]; voy a intentar la manera, solo le agrego los paramatros en donde esta tu comentario de  //Enviar dato de usuario?